# Math in comments gets doubled up when you edit

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing a comment containing formulae will mangle the formulae](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/editing-a-comment-containing-formulae-will-mangle-the-formulae)

(This question appears subjective and is likely to be closed :-))

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a post with not too many comments on it.
2. Post a comment involving some math (e.g. `My $f(x)$ is bigger than your $g(y)$.`).
3. Reload the page.
4. Click the edit link.

Expected behavior: you see and can edit the text `My $f(x)$ is bigger than your $g(y)$.`
Actual behavior: you see and can edit the text `My f(x)f(x) is bigger than your g(y)g(y).`

This bug doesn't seem to happen if you post your comment in a really long comment thread (i.e. if you need to fetch your comment from the server before editing). It also doesn't happen if you edit your comment before reloading the page.

(somebody please add a tag like [editing] to this question)

Comment: Not subjective, but a duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/459/editing-a-comment-containing-formulae-will-mangle-the-formulae -- please upvote that question and/or add an answer there.